# Does std::optional change signature of the function?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdoptional

I need to make an optional argument with a default value in my function. Currently the signature looks something like this:

```
void func(int a, std::optional<int> b = 10)
```

and the function behaves in the following way:

```
func(15, 5); // works
func(15);    // works
```

The question is: If I remove the explicit initialization for the optional argument, like this:

```
void func(int a, std::optional<int> b)
```

Then It seems like the signature of the function changes

```
func(15, 5); // works
func(15);    // fails
```

Which makes me very confused about the purpose of the `std::optional` in the first place. What is it good for if not for creating optional arguments?

Comment: `std::optional` is a class just like any other so it must be initialized. The only way you can omit an argument is when one has a default argument.

Comment: It does not make much sense to have an `optional` with a default value that is not empty as it would only confuse people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is it good for if not for creating optional arguments?

[`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) is not supposed to be used for optional argument what you expect; which requires [default argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) as your 1st code sample showed, `std::optional` won't change the language syntax.

> The class template `std::optional` manages an optional contained value, i.e. a value that may or may not be present.

You can used it like

```
void func(int a, std::optional<int> b = std::nullopt) {
    if (b) {
        // if b contains a value
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

then

```
func(15, 5); // b will contain a value (i.e. `5`)
func(15);    // b doesn't contain a value
```

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense to me. Found it really hard to get to the bottom of this from just cpp docs, so had to ask here.

Answer (score 1):

`std::optional<int>` is still a concrete type despite being "optional" so, unless you have a default value for it in your function specification, you need to supply one.

You *seem* to be conflating the two definitions of optional here:

- the concrete type allowing you to store an object or lack thereof; and
- the optionality (if that's even a real word) of function arguments.

They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Another use: optional return values:

```
// throws if cannot parse
auto parse_int(const std::string& s) -> int;

// returns std::nullopt if it cannot parse
auto try_parse_int(const std::string& s) -> std::optional<int>
```